# Prolog simple assignment not simple for me

Tags: prolog

I must say that I don't understand this language at all but I want to learn it by example so please understand me. I have to write out all persons
that have borrowed at least two items (by id and letter of these persons).

Here is simple database :)

```
person(1,"A").
person(2,"B").
person(3,"C").
person(4,"D").
person(5,"E").
person(6,"F").

borrowed(1001,1).
borrowed(1002,1).
borrowed(2001,1).
borrowed(1004,2).
borrowed(1005,4).
borrowed(2003,4).
borrowed(2005,5).
borrowed(2006,5).
```

Comment: Add the code you've started with.

Comment: Well that's the point i solved 4 other assignments but i stopped at this one. I dont know how to connect this two tables and how to write it properly.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't meant as a homework help site, though. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: It's not homework. I am just learning this stuff, because i need it. I found it on some site and im trying to look for answers that it. It's not assigntments its simple task that i cant solve that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `person/2` is defined as `person( unique-id , name )` and that your `borrowed/2` represents `borrowed( id-of-borrowed-item , person-id-of-borrower )`, something like this ought to do you:

```
borrower_by_count( Name , N ) :-
  person(Id,Name) ,              % find the person 
  findall(X,borrowed(X,Id),Xs) , % find all the items they've borrowed
  length(Xs,N).                  % check the length:
```

This will work for any value of N. Something like `borrower_by_count( Name , 3 ).` should return

```
Name = "A"
```

and `borrower_by_count( Name , 2 ).` should return (as you backtrack into it):

```
Name = "D"
Name = "E'
```

It also works the other way: `borrowed( "A" , N )` should return

```
N = 3.
```

And if both arguments are unbound, it should successively enumerate each person and the number of item's they've borrowed.